# Permission issues in WhatsApp Business Platform API

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I have a Meta App for using WhatsApp Business Platform. So I follower every instruction on the official docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/get-started#1--acquire-an-access-token-using-a-system-user-or-facebook-login):

- Added a system user
- Gave administrator permissions
- Created the bearer token
- Assigned the app as an asset and gave total permission
- On WhatsApp account I added the system user and gave total permission.

Yet I get (#200) You do not have permission to access this field on every request! Or similar error messages.
What else do I need to do?

EDIT: Im trying to send a message [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{my](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/%7Bmy) phone id}/messages and the exact message Im getting there is  `You do not have the necessary permissions required to send messages on behalf of this WhatsApp Business Account` and error code 200.

I used the Access Token Debugger and these are my permissions `business_management, whatsapp_business_management, whatsapp_business_messaging, public_profile` so it should be fine.

Also, I checked that my user has a role in the app, and it's an administrator.

Comment: Which API request you are getting the error?

Comment: The `whatsapp_business_management` permission. If your app needs to access endpoints targeting your business account, you'll also need the `business_management` permission.

Comment: @turivishal I get that on any endpoint I reach. Or similar error.

Comment: @neopheus Im using this to send whatsapp messages from a business account. If I need that permission, how I add it? Because I remember adding whatsapp_business_management but I can't find where.

Comment: @here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions

Comment: Can you send message from through a temporary token from the developer app?

Comment: @turivishal yes I can. I also updated the post with more info.

Comment: @neopheus there weren't permission issues. I updated the post with more info.